# Connecting Two 12 Volt 10 Amp Power Supplies Together

Tags: power-supply

I am trying to power a 12V 120W Thermoelectric Water Cooling System Device, but the 12 Volt 120 watt Power supply does not seem to be enough and the fans whine. Can I add another identical 10 Amp power supply by splicing the output wires of 2 units together to make one 20 Amp Power Supply?
[image]

[image][image]

Comment: yes. Probably the fan pulls very little power.

Comment: @ronsimpson I'm sure it is not the fans as well and the peltier module pulling the most watts but the whining fans is a result of not having enough power in total.

Comment: The problem may be switching supplies they do not play well in parallel compared to Linear supplies, also the type of load matters, thermoelectric should be ok but motors are not so good with switching type. I have had problems with 20 amp switching supplies that the same load on a linear was ok at 12 amp.

Comment: When you parallel two supplies, usually one supply pulls the full 10A and goes into current limit the other supply picks up the rest of the load.  I think you should splice very close to the load and have long wires to the supplies.  This will add some small amount of resistance to each output.  This will help share the load better.

Comment: Add power resistors (0.047 ohm, 10W) in series to both sources and connect them together. Some drop (like 0.5V) will be presented. Also you cannot drain 20A but with 16A it should work.

Comment: A couple high current Schottky diodes might work. Otherwise, maybe you can use an adjustable power resistor and move the slider until the currents are about equal.

Comment: @ronsimpson how much longer?

Comment: From the picture, the cooler looks to be two similar units connected together and wired in parallel. If so, it would be better to split the wiring and power each half with its own supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends what output voltage difference the sources have.

Schematic below:

Adding series resistances (47mOhm) and considering 0.2V voltage diff. the drain currents are divided in ratio 10A for higher voltage supply and 6A for lower one when load drains 16A.
Resistances causes drop about 0.3V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1h7CZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>